# Pivot non numeric dataframe python

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gfWk.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDwph.jpg)

Hi Dear Friends, 
I have a little problem while trying to pivot my dataframe
I tried to put the column 0 as the columns and the column 1 as values.
But that doesn't give me what i expected.
I don't know why there are NaN everywhere 
Anyone can help me to structure this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like that `pivot()` with setting only `columns=` and `values=` creates a cross table with index (0,1,2,…) and the column.
How about preparing new columns with same value and setting the column to `index=` of `pivot()` as following?

```
    columns1['tmp'] = 0  
    columns1.pivot(columns=0 , values=1 , index='tmp').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much clear, I have set an id and it works :)